# ASP GridView Button (custom vs auto generate)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I spent an hour screwing with this, so maybe after all these years of benefiting from other's posts to StackOverflow, I may give just a little back.

I wanted a button field in my grid view.  When fired, it would make a call to the DB and pull more complete data back to be edited.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvXXX" runat="server" Caption="XXX Search Results" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
      Width="50%" DataKeyNames="XXXID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvXXX_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <Columns>  
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit XXX Data" CommandName="Select"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="XXXID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="XXX Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SSN" HeaderText="SSN" />
        </Columns>  
        <EmptyDataTemplate>No Match Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I enter a partial name in my lookup, hit the look up button, code behind works through the layers to the data layer, makes the DB call, returns the records, and the grid view gets populated.  GREAT!

But when ever I click the edit button in the gridview, *gvXXX_SelectedIndexChanged* fires, the method is called, but the gridview is empty in the code behind.

Time is money, I don't want to spend a lot of time with this, so I put **AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"** back into the gridview, and now I have data again.  I'm not sure why the difference, or what I wired up wrong, but I'm moving on.  A pretty button would be nicer than a link, but I've got other fish to fry.

Comment: You need to include more code in your question. Where do you provide data source? what's the code for gvXXX_SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: short answer: your  "Button" selection is triggering a "postback" due to the "gvXXX_SelectedIndexChanged"  (as it should)  Your data source gets regenerated and the (search)  parameters are not saved. 
would help to see the rest of code.